# Read more than 32 bytes from memory (Assembly)

Tags: bytes, assembly

Assume I am passing a variable bytes (memory) to a function. This variable corresponds to A concatenated with B where A is of size 32 and B is 96 bytes, how can I return A (bytes32) and B (bytes).

```
function readData(bytes memory data) public returns (bytes32, bytes memory){
    bytes32 A;
    bytes memory B;
    assembly{
        A:= mload(add(data,0x20))
        calldatacopy(B,0x45,0xA0) // not sure about this
    }
    return (A,B);
}
```

## **Edit**

knowing the length of B make things easy but the things is that B size can change, therefore hardcoding a sequence of `mload` (one per word of data) won't do. this could be solved with an assembly loop but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: I just updated the question, I can get A (first 32 bytes). I think I could get B using a loop but looks dirty. I tried to get the call data but doesn't work (remix crashes), any ideas? is there a way to this directly on the input variable data?

Comment: In `public` functions, you should not assume call data to contain function arguments, because call data is basically the same as `msg.data`, i.e. it refers to parameters of the whole smart contract call rather than particular function call.

Comment: the only thing to take into account in msg.data will be the 4bytes of the function selector, no?

Comment: No, `public` function (in contrast to `external` functions) could be called from another function of the same contract with arguments that are completely different from what is in `msg.data`.

Comment: You are right. Got it.

Comment: Regarding **Edit** part.  Am I right that you need first 32 bytes of data to go to A, and the rest bytes to go to B?  If so, then you definitely need loop.

Comment: Yes, I will need the loop. Thanks for your answer, from here I can manage to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function readData (bytes memory data)
public pure returns (bytes32 a, bytes memory b) {
  require (data.length == 0x80);
  assembly {
    a := mload (add (data, 0x20)) // A
    b := mload (0x40) // Free memory pointer
    mstore (0x40, add (b, 0x80)) // Advance free memory pointer
    mstore (b, 0x60) // B length
    mstore (add (b, 0x20), mload (add (data, 0x40))) // First word of B
    mstore (add (b, 0x40), mload (add (data, 0x60))) // Second word of B
    mstore (add (b, 0x60), mload (add (data, 0x80))) // Third word of B
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This does not solve my problem completely but from here I can get what I need.